# Can we start user session from windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service

Is it possible to start the user session in console mode from windows service on start up without login manually?

I tried some dll but it is not working. Any windows dll are there for implementing the same thing?

Comment: What *problem* are you trying to solve where you think this is part of the solution? It may be that you're looking for something (e.g. Kiosk mode) and just don't know the right terms to search on. Also, "I tried some dll but it is not working" doesn't help us to help you - *What* DLL/method(s) have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

No. And it makes sense, which user will it be if you don't log in?

Comment: I understand the answer "no" is disappointing but sometimes it's just the answer.